# How to run a Dockerfile locally on a Windows 10 machine?

Tags: docker, windows-10, dockerfile

I'm new to Docker and I'm trying to run a dockerfile locally on my machine to make sure everything is working correctly before uploading it to GitHub and trying it out on another server. Is there a way to do that? I've installed the Docker for Windows 10 and I'm able to navigate to the folder in which the dockerfile exist. When I try to execute the '''docker build -t file_name -f file_name''' I get an error.

I've already downloaded Docker and able to access things correctly. I've tried 
'''docker build''' but that doesn't seem to work.

I'm expecting for the dockerfile to run and build successfully. Instead it just errors out during build.

Comment: What error do you get?  What are the contents of the Dockerfile?

Comment: Gonna need to be more specific about the error message at least.

Comment: Command is this: 
docker build -t Dockerfile -f Dockerfile
According to the documentation you can name it Dockerfile. 
Error is: invalid argument "Dockerfile" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

Comment: Contents are: 
FROM balenalib/raspberry-pi-debian-python:3.7.2

Comment: what r u exactly going to do with that docker file, just use docker to run the application based containers, use Power Shell or Git bash on win.10. Don't confuse yourself too much

Answer (score 12):

The error has already told you all things:

> invalid argument "Dockerfile" for "-t, --tag" flag: invalid reference format: repository name must be lowercase

You could change command to next to have a try:

```
docker build -t abc -f Dockerfile .
```

Above, `abc` is the repo name you tagged for your new image, it should be `lowercase` as said from the error, meanwhile, the last `.` need to be added as it will specify the build context.

Example reference to [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#tag-an-image--t).